# How to set the correct path to files connected via URL in SCSS

Tags: webpack, sass, pug, webpack-5

Problem with image/icon file paths connected in scss using:
`background: url(../images/bg-blue.svg);`

When setting outputPath in the plugin :

```
new PugPlugin({
    pretty: true,
    css: {
        enabled: true,
        test: /\.(css|scss|sass|less|styl)$/,
        outputPath: 'assets/css/',
    },
}),
```

My styles and images rules:

```
  test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
  use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
},
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|ico|svg)/,
  type: 'asset/resource',
  generator: {
  // output filename of images
  filename: 'assets/images/[name].[hash:8][ext]',
  },
},
```

Output options:

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/'),
  filename: 'assets/js/[name].js',
  path: __dirname + '/dist',
  assetModuleFilename: path
      .join('assets/images', '[name][ext]')
      .replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  clean: true,
}
```

Regarding the file structure of the build - everything is fine, as I need to
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJj3Z.png)

The css is generated in the right, specified folder, but the paths to the icons remain unchanged relative to the root, like this :
`background:url(assets/images/bg-blue.73cdd532.svg);`

But I need a file relative to the specified directory:
`background: url(../images/bg-blue.73cdd532.svg);`

> "webpack": "^5.75.0",

> "pug-plugin": "^4.9.2",

> OS Win

Without `outputPath`  it works, but that's not what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear `outputPath` in PugPlugin options and add rule for css&js files with right path :

```
new PugPlugin({
  pretty: true,
  css: {
      filename: 'assets/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
  },
  js: {
      filename: 'assets/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js', 
  },
}),
```

And remove `assetModuleFilename` in output options:

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/'),
  filename: 'assets/js/[name].js',
  path: __dirname + '/dist',
  clean: true,
}
```